# When Adding Fragment: IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-theme, android-styles

I have checked I'm using theme.compat both in activity and fragment. basically I'm attaching fragment statically to activity and getting this error:

> IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme

MainActivity:

```
ActMain extends AppCompatActivity
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_act_main);
}
```

main_activity.xml

```
<fragment android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:name="com.example.xyz.reusablefragments.FragOne"
android:id="@+id/fragment" android:layout_gravity="center"/>
```

manifest:

```
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    (<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">)
```

fragment:

```
public class FragOne extends Fragment
```

Comment: Why don't you use Appcompat theme?

Comment: Its <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"> in style

Comment: Try using Theme.AppCompat.Light without actionbar

Comment: why actionbar and fragment can't coexist?

Comment: Why i have to use noactionbar?

Comment: No, it should work as it is. I asked you to change it to see if it crashes because of it. I use both themes and they work fine. NoActionBar removes ActionBar from your activity and prevents crashing if you use ToolBar from design library.

Comment: Yes it was crashing because of actionbar theme, But i didn't included toolbar anywhere, why it was crashing,